# Как сделать одно модальное окно для всех картинок галереи на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, у меня есть некоторое количество картинок на сайте. Я хочу, чтобы при клике на изображение открывалось модальное окно с этим изображением. Как мне сделать так, чтобы в одном и том же всплывающем окне открывались разные картинки. Не делать же мне 500 модальных окон на каждое изображение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете посмотреть как это сделано тут и уже написать как вам удобнее:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-image-gallery-in-a-modal

Либо если совсем просто:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
        $('.pop').on('click', function() {
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        });     
});
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. "Совсем просто" - это как раз то, что мне нужно))